# Undefined is not an object (evaluating StatusBarManager.HEIGHT) react-native 0.55.4

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I've just upgraded to react-native 0.55.4. After successfully getting it up and running on iOS, I'm now getting it up and running on Android. I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined is not an object (evaluating StatusBarManager.HEIGHT)
```

[image: Android emulator NOT connected to devtools]

I tracked `StatusBarManager.HEIGHT` down to `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/StatusBar/StatusBar.js`. This is the only location in my entire codebase where `StatusBarManager.HEIGHT` is being accessed & it's in the `react-native` package itself. Any ideas why this is happening? I've searched everywhere for a solution.

For some reason I get a different error when I connect my emulator to the react devtools:

[image: Android emulator red screen error]

Comment: could you please share the import statement for StatusBarManager

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I'm not importing `StatusBarManager` anywhere. I tracked down the only place where `StatusBarManager.HEIGHT` is accessed to the `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/StatusBar/StatusBar.js`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem is that I missed a package inside *MainApplication.java*

The package is `new MainReactPackage()` inside *getPackages()* method.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import { Platform, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { StatusBarManager } = NativeModules;

const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 34 : StatusBarManager.HEIGHT;
```

On iOS, you can use getHeight()

```
StatusBarManager.getHeight((statusBarHeight)=>{
  console.log(statusBarHeight)
})
```